# "tail -f" style web application

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, tail

I've been searching for a small but functional PHP script or similar that I can expose via apache. Basically I'd like what "tail -f /var/log/something" does, but visible via a web browser. I'm finding various solutions, but most of them operate with something similar to "tail -10" under the hood - which is fine if the log is "slow" in writing - as you can imagine data can be "lost" between poll attempts of more than that number of lines was written.

Is there anything lightweight that satisfies what I am looking for? Something like Splunk is way beyond what I need or want.

Comment: I actually submitted the "tail -f" feature request for Splunk several years ago.  What didn't you like about Splunk for this requirement?

Comment: Splunk has a high footprint compared to what you would see with a simple script. I am using it for the moment - it's like using a backhoe to blank a flower.

Answer (score 2):

For realtime tailing, you probably want websockets. Node.js comes to mind. See [the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499152/minimum-websocket-nodejs-tail-example). Edit: guess that answer suggested but didn't implement socket.io. I'd google around  for [nodejs tail dash f](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nodejs+tail+dash+f)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tail, you could diff your current content against the file, and just remove "> " from each of the diff output before adding it to the page.